# are app caches redundant when using serverless architecture (e.g. Amazon Lambda via python Zappa)

Tags: django, caching, redis, memcached, aws-lambda

Django [advises](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/) on using a Redis or Memcached cache for high traffic sites, to cut down on the work done by the server.

Apps running on [Amazon Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_UK&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=lambda_b&sc_content=lambda_e&sc_detail=amazon%20lambda&sc_category=lambda&sc_segment=186455828798&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=UK&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!186455828798!e!!g!!amazon%20lambda&ef_id=VrmsZQAAAJVNqU2K:20170629103204:s) via [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) have fantastic horizontal scale-ability. There does not seem to be the need to minimise the processing efforts of a server when another server can be fired up easily and very cheaply.

Are Caches such as Memcached and Redis redundant when using server-less architectures?

UPDATE: having CDN (eg cloudfront) infront of your app is still adviseable (eg [by Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#serving-static-files--binary-uploads)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a serverless architecture might change the equation a bit when it comes to application caches. It does solve *some* of the things that a cache helps with.

One very important thing that it doesn't solve, though, is database load, which will probably be the bottleneck in a serverless architecture. (It might even make it worse, due to the difficulty of connection pooling.)

So I expect that serverless applications will still make full use of the application cache.